Why are http requests automatically transferred to https by browser
I have hosted an express.js app on amazon ec2 instance using node index.js. In my index.html I have following 2 lines in <head>


  <script type="module" src="http://51.20.7.73:5000/buildjs.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://51.20.7.73:5000/buildcss.css">



But the problem is that when this HTML is rendered in chrome browser, these requests are automatically converted to https instead of http which is giving error in the console as follows

My page is itself hosted to http : http://51.20.7.73:5000/
and when I separately open http://51.20.7.73:5000/buildjs.js in browser, it is serving the file correctly.
I don't know why are these requests transferred to HTTPS automatically, but due to this my react page is not working, Can someone please help? Thanks!

Are you using helmet for your NodeJS application? Do you use NGINX in front of that web application? Apache?

I am not using helmet, for now I just hosted it using "node index.js" to test it @AllanChua

Could this be kind of a duplicate of this question?
https://superuser.com/questions/565409/how-to-stop-an-automatic-redirect-from-http-to-https-in-chrome
Or to be more precise, do you want to disable the https conversion in Chrome or adapt your code that it can handle http and https?

But this will only do it in my browser, what if someone else opens it, It will not work for them. And why does chrome behave like this?

Mostly because http is considered insecure and should be replaced with https. So to "help" normal users browsers often enforce https.

You will have to use helmet for express to prevent the hsts related headers that instructs the browser to use HTTPS for all the requests made from your site.
import express from 'express';
import helmet from 'helmet';

const app = express();

// Use Helmet to set various HTTP 
// headers for security, except HSTS and CORS
app.use(helmet({
  hsts: false, // Disable HSTS
  crossOriginResourcePolicy: false, // Disable CORS headers for HTTP use-case
}));

// This will prolly get replaced by
// static asset serving for the home page
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, world!');
});

// Start the server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});


This is generating a new error in console: "The Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy header has been ignored, because the URL's origin was untrustworthy. It was defined either in the final response or a redirect. Please deliver the response using the HTTPS protocol. You can also use the 'localhost' origin instead."

@ShlokJain, this what I've realized so I added the code for CORS. BTW, hosting your server in bare metal is not a common setup and is only practical for quick prototyping. In a more professional setup, your EC2 will have a load balancer in front. This is why the native behaviour of helmet is to attach the HSTS and CORS headers.
